# link to anchor on current page using PODOFO in PDF

Tags: c++, pdf, podofo

I am trying to use PODOFO in c++ to create a text in PDF. After clicking the text, it can move to a specific page/ area in the same PDF.
My final goal is to create a table of content in PDF. The following code is what I am doing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <podofo/podofo.h>

using namespace PoDoFo;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
try {
    string filename = std::string(argv[0]) + "testtesttesttest.pdf";
    PdfStreamedDocument* document = new PdfStreamedDocument(filename.c_str());
    PdfPage* pPage1;
    PdfPainter painter;
    PdfFont* pFont;
    pPage1 = document->CreatePage( PdfPage::CreateStandardPageSize( ePdfPageSize_A4 ) );
    painter.SetPage(pPage1);
    if( !pPage1 ) {
        PODOFO_RAISE_ERROR( ePdfError_InvalidHandle );
    }
    pFont = document->CreateFont( "Arial" );
    if( !pFont ) {
        PODOFO_RAISE_ERROR( ePdfError_InvalidHandle );
    }
    pFont->SetFontSize( 18.0 );
    painter.SetFont( pFont );
    painter.DrawText( 56.69, pPage1->GetPageSize().GetHeight() - 56.69, "Hello World!" );
    PdfPage* pPage2 = document->CreatePage( PdfPage::CreateStandardPageSize( ePdfPageSize_Letter ) );
    painter.SetPage( pPage1 );
    this->drawHyperLinkText(&painter, pPage1, pPage2, document );
    //painter.SetPage( pPage2 );
    painter.FinishPage();
    document->GetInfo()->SetCreator ( PdfString("examplehelloworld - A PoDoFo test application") );
    document->GetInfo()->SetAuthor  ( PdfString("Dominik Seichter") );
    document->GetInfo()->SetTitle   ( PdfString("Hello World 222") );
    document->GetInfo()->SetSubject ( PdfString("Testing the PoDoFo PDF Library") );
    document->GetInfo()->SetKeywords( PdfString("Test;PDF;Hello World;") );
    document->Close();
} catch( const PdfError & eCode ) {
    eCode.PrintErrorMsg();
}
   return 0;
}

void drawHyperLinkText( PdfPainter* pPainter, PdfPage* pPage1, PdfPage* pPage2, PdfStreamedDocument* pDocument )
{
    PdfString sJap(reinterpret_cast<const pdf_utf8*>("test"));
    PdfAnnotation* pAnnotation = pPage2->CreateAnnotation( ePdfAnnotation_Link, PdfRect( 400.0, 200.0, 20.0, 20.0 ) );
    PdfString sGerman(reinterpret_cast<const pdf_utf8*>("Unicode Umlauts: ÄÖÜß"));
    pAnnotation->SetTitle( sGerman );
    pAnnotation->SetContents( sJap );
    pAnnotation->SetOpen( true );
    pAnnotation->SetDestination(pPage1);
}
```

I dun know I am doing right or not. I create two pages and want to add the text in page. When I click the text, it would move back to page 1. But it always crashes at the final line  `pAnnotation->SetDestination(pPage1);` .

May anyone give me some helps or an example to do that? Thanks

Comment: Please show a [mre]. Is Qt even needed to make a small example? If not, don't include Qt.

Comment: removed the tag. Thanks

Comment: Good. Now, if you could provide a minimal example of code that we can actually compile and that will reproduce the error, it would  be great. I made a small example of your code but that doesn't cause any problems so we're lacking information.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks you for your suggestion. Try my best to remove all the qt elements.

Comment: Better - but you can't compile this, can you? Please verify that it compiles on your computer first and then update the question.

Comment: Fwiw: I corrected the errors in your code above to make it compile and I don't get any problems except memory leaks (since you don't `delete` what you've `new`ed). I had to remove the line `this->drawHyperLinkText(&painter, pPage1, pPage2, document);` though since there is no `this` in `main`.

Comment: I has posted all my code.  The problem is that  I would crash in this line
'pAnnotation->SetDestination(pPage1); '

I dun know that is it a right way to do the link to anchor on current page?

Comment: Ok, now it became worse. With all that Qt stuff in there, it's not _minimal_ anymore. We can't even compile it since we don't have `"ui_mainwindow.h"` so it's not _reproducible_ either. Please remove the Qt dependencies.

Comment: Removed all the Qt dependencies.  Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: Better again :-) Though I'm surprised that your compiler lets you compile the line `string filename = argv[0] + "testtesttesttest.pdf";` - mine don't. You must `#include <string>` and you can't concatenate C strings like that. It should be `std::string filename = std::string(argv[0]) + "testtesttesttest.pdf";` - And the line `this->drawHyperLinkText(&painter, pPage1, pPage2, document);` should definitely not compile. The only thing left are memory leaks, nothing else that I can see.

Comment: I changed this part wrongly. I tried to debug in qt and it crashed in this line. pAnnotation->SetDestination(pPage1); but  I dun know the reason as I have stored the page1 and page2.

Comment: If I change it from pPage1 to pPage2(annotation page), then it works

Comment: I only fixed the memory leak and compiled the program with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined,leak` and it reports no problems. I also used `valgrind` - still no problems reported. You still have the line `this->drawHyperLinkText(&painter, pPage1, pPage2, document );` in the code. What is that suppsoed to do? It can't compile with that line in there.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I want to build the table of content. When I click the text in the table of contents page, it would route to that page. Also I want to create a text in page 10 and click ,it would move to a specific page like page 2. Can you do such example for me please? thanks.

Comment: If you can you make a reproducible example I will have a look.

Comment: @TedLyngmo It appears to me that the line "this->drawHyperLinkText(&painter, pPage1, pPage2, document );" in the code should instead be "drawHyperLinkText(&painter, pPage1, pPage2, document );", since the "drawHyperLinkText" function is below "main".  However, the function should probably be moved above the "main" function, or a function prototype should be created for it that is above the main function, since otherwise the compiler will have to guess at its parameter types when compiling the call to it.

Comment: @SomeGuy I'm sorry, but I don't have the patience to read and interpret more than simple onelines in comments, especially not if not code-formatted. I also don't recall what this 2 year old topic that OP never cared to clarify in a [mre] was about.